# Scraping lunar/solar eclipse data with BeautifulSoup Followup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I decided to refactor my code based on this [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195245/scraping-lunar-solar-eclipse-data-with-beautifulsoup).

**Eclipse**:

```
class Eclipse():

    def __init__(self, eclipse_date, eclipse_type, eclipse_location):
        self._validate_str_parameters(eclipse_date, "Eclipse date")
        self._validate_str_parameters(eclipse_type, "Eclipse type")
        self._validate_lst_parameters(eclipse_location, "Location")

        self._eclipse_date = eclipse_date
        self._eclipse_type = eclipse_type
        self._eclipse_location = eclipse_location


    def _validate_str_parameters(self, str_to_validate, parameter_type):
       if not isinstance(str_to_validate, str):
           raise TypeError("{0} is the incorrect type".format(parameter_type))
       if not str_to_validate:
           raise ValueError("{0} is empty".format(parameter_type))     

    def _validate_lst_parameters(self, lst_to_validate, parameter_type):
        if not isinstance(lst_to_validate, list):
            raise TypeError("{0} type is incorrect".format(parameter_type))
        if len(lst_to_validate) == 0:
            raise ValueError("{0} is invalid. You must have at least one.".format(parameter_type))

    @property
    def get_eclipse_date(self):
        return self._eclipse_date

    @property
    def get_eclipse_type(self):
        return self._eclipse_type

    @property
    def get_eclipse_location(self):
        return self._eclipse_location

    def date_and_type(self):
        return "{0}\n{1}\n".format(self._eclipse_date, self._eclipse_type)

    def month_and_year_is(self, eclipse_month, eclipse_year):
        self._validate_str_parameters(eclipse_month, "Month")
        self._validate_str_parameters(eclipse_year, "Year")
        return eclipse_month and eclipse_year in self._eclipse_date

    def takesplacein(self, country):
       self._validate_str_parameters(country, "Country")

       country_formatted = country.strip().title()
       muchof = "Much of {0}".format(country_formatted)
       return self._is_muchof_in_list(muchof) or self._is_country_in_list(country_formatted)

    def _is_muchof_in_list(self, muchofcountry):
        return muchofcountry in self._eclipse_location

    def _is_country_in_list(self, countryformatted):
        return countryformatted in self._eclipse_location

    def __str__(self):
        return "Date: {0}\nType: {1}\nLocation: {2}\n" .format(self._eclipse_date,self._eclipse_type,self._eclipse_location)
```

**Explanation**:
I created this class to create objects based on the data I scraped from this [eclipse](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/) site.

Example Data after scraping:

```
Date: July 13, 2018 
Type: Partial Solar Eclipse
Location: ['South in Australia', ' Pacific', ' Indian Ocean']

Date: July 27, 2018 
Type: Total Lunar Eclipse
Location: ['Much of Europe', ' Much of Asia', ' Australia', ' Africa', ' South in North America', ' South America', ' Pacific', ' Atlantic', ' Indian Ocean', ' Antarctica']
```

The method `takesplacein(self, country)`  takes the `country` (for example, europe) and using  `muchof = "Much of {0}".format(country_formatted)`, creates the phrase "Much of Europe."

The site uses that phrase when not all of the country will see it, without testing for "Much of *insert country here*" we would just test the country name, but it will return `False`, even though parts of the country will see it.

The method tests for both "Much of *insert country here*" **or** the Country itself, because there can only be one occurrence of the country. It will never say Europe **and** Much of Europe.

Eclipse concerns:

1. Are the method names `takesplacein(self, country)` and `month_and_year_is(self, month, year)` considered clean? I personally like the names because then I can write code that almost sounds like a sentence, for example:

   ```
   if eclipse.takesplacein("europe"):
       print(eclipse.date_and_type())

   if eclipse.month_and_year_is("July", "2018"):
       print(eclipse.date_and_type())
   ```
2. Is the use of `isinstance()` justified here? I'm aware the use of that method or keyword is considered code smell, but without it, I can pass a `string` as the location when the code uses location as a `list`

**Main**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from Eclipse import Eclipse
from collections import namedtuple


def generate_eclipse_data(eclipse_info):

    eclipse_list = []

    for info in eclipse_info:
        retrieved_date_and_type = parse_date_and_type(info.find('a').text)
        retrieved_location_data = parse_location(info.find('p').text)
        eclipse_data = Eclipse(retrieved_date_and_type.date,retrieved_date_and_type.type, retrieved_location_data.location)
        eclipse_list.append(eclipse_data)
    return eclipse_list

def parse_location(info_to_clean):
    clean_location = namedtuple("Clean_Location",["location"])
    cleanup_location_and_new_features = info_to_clean.split(" New Features")
    cleanup_location, *rest, new_features = cleanup_location_and_new_features
    location_list = cleanup_location.split(",")
    location_data = clean_location(location_list)
    return location_data

def parse_date_and_type(info_to_split):
    date_and_type = namedtuple("Date_Type", ["date", "type"])
    eclipse_split_data = info_to_split.split("—")
    eclipse_date, *rest, eclipse_type = eclipse_split_data
    eclipse_data = date_and_type(eclipse_date,eclipse_type.strip())
    return eclipse_data

def main():

    eclipse_url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/"
    eclipse_time_date = requests.get(eclipse_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(eclipse_time_date.text, 'html.parser')
    eclipse_info = soup.find_all("div", class_= "six columns art__eclipse-txt")
    eclipse_filename = 'eclipse.txt'

    if (len(eclipse_info) > 0):
        try:
            print("URL: {0}\n".format(eclipse_url))
            eclipse_data =  generate_eclipse_data(eclipse_info)

            for eclipse in eclipse_data:
                if eclipse.takesplacein("europe"):
                    print(eclipse.date_and_type())

            for eclipse in eclipse_data:
                if eclipse.month_and_year_is("July", "2018"):
                    print(eclipse.date_and_type())
        except ValueError as error:
            print(error)
        except TypeError as error:
            print(error)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
    else:
        print("No data available")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`def parse_location(info_to_clean):` constructs a `list` and stores it in a `namedtuple`.

Any ways I can improve it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is the use of `isinstance()` justified?

Part of what you are trying to validate with the `isinstance()` is the Date strings.  I would suggest that this whole thing would be better done by converting to and using `datetime.date` objects.  This would mean the validation could come when the conversion is done.  That, at least for the date, would remove the need for the `isinstance()`.

#### Are the method names `takesplacein` and `month_and_year_is` clean?

I would suggest `takesplacein` would read better as `takes_place_in` and `month_and_year_is` would read better `is_month_and_year`.  But to your larger point, I also prefer these sorts of names because as you note they allow the code to read better.

#### Properties don't really need *get_*

These properties are named with `get_` prefix.  In the case of properties, the fact that it returns something is reasonably obvious, so `get_` doesn't really provide more information. So:

```
@property
def get_eclipse_date(self):
    return self._eclipse_date

@property
def get_eclipse_type(self):
    return self._eclipse_type
```

Would be a bit cleaner as simply:

```
@property
def eclipse_date(self):
    return self._eclipse_date

@property
def eclipse_type(self):
    return self._eclipse_type
```

additionally, I would consider make this a property also:

```
def date_and_type(self):
    return "{0}\n{1}\n".format(self._eclipse_date, self._eclipse_type)
```

Comment: Also, if all the property does is returning the value of an internal attribute it is not actually needed (you can always make it a property later if you want to add caching or something like that)

Comment: I gave you the checkmark, but why didn't you just edit your original post?

Comment: The original post, stated it was only about Main.  It was the next day when I realized I some time to comment on the other code.  Seemed like a different post...  Cheers.

Comment: This might go beyond the scope of the question, but is using `isinstance()` justified when validating constructor parameters? If I didn't, you could pass a string when the constructor expects a `list` and the code would break.

Answer (score 1):

This review is only for the code in **Main**.  A few style suggestions, in no particular order:

#### Extra Intermediate Variables

Separate variable names for intermediate products are useful in a few cases, eg:

1. The name of the variable is important to document what the intermediate product represents.
2. Need to break a very complex expression down into smaller pieces.
3. The intermediate product is used in more than one place.

So, I would suggest that this:

```
cleanup_location_and_new_features = info_to_clean.split("? New Features")
cleanup_location, *rest, new_features = cleanup_location_and_new_features
location_list = cleanup_location.split(",")
location_data = clean_location(location_list)
```

is actually easier to read as:

```
cleanup_location, *rest, new_features = info_to_clean.split("? New Features")
location_data = clean_location(cleanup_location.split(","))
```

I don't think the two intermediate variable names provide any more clarity or functionality, but they do double the code line count.

#### Multiple Exception Types:

This:

```
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
except TypeError as error:
    print(error)
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Can be reduced to:

```
except (ValueError, TypeError, Exception) as error:
    print(error)
```

But then since `ValueError` and `TypeError` are both based on `Exception` it could be further reduced to:

```
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

But catching all exceptions is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice), so you may want to consider what functionality you really want here..

#### Remove Redundant Parenthesis:

```
if (len(eclipse_info) > 0):
```

Can simply be:

```
if len(eclipse_info) > 0:
```

anything `> 0` will evaluate to True so you can just do:

```
if len(eclipse_info):
```

And finally many types evaluate to True if their `len` is `> 0`, and for those types you can simply do:

```
if eclipse_info:
```

#### PEP8

You should consider formatting your code in accordance with [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  This is important when sharing code, as the consistent style makes it much easier for other programmers to read your code.  There are various tools available to assist in making the code pep8 compliant.  I use the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE which will show pep8 violations right in the editor.

Comment: see how you were able to do this: `except (ValueError, TypeError, Exception) as error:`, is there a term for that, like *exception packing*?

Comment: No term that I am aware of.  Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470428/7311767